# how to dojo button background invisible or remove?

Tags: javascript, dojo, arcgis, arcgis-js-api

I`m trying to put an image in place of dojo button. I am able to add the image, as background, but, the outline of the button is visible. I would want ot show the image only. What should I do?

my code is follows.

css:

```
.EditButtonWidgetImage {
    background-image: url("EditButton/images/edit.png");
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 25px;
    width: 25px;
}
```

javascript:

```
var infoTableContainer = dojo.create("div", null, map.container);

    var x = 200 - map.position.x;
    var y = 50 - map.position.y;

    this.InfoTable = new FloatingPane({
        title : "<b>Editor</b>",
        resizable: true,
        doLayout: true,
        dockable: false,
        closable: true,
        //constrainToContainer: true,
        'class': "EditWidgetContainer",
        style: "left:"+x+"px;top:"+y+"px;padding:0px"
    }, infoTableContainer);
    //dojo.attr(infoTable, 'class', 'TableInfoWidgetContainer'); //ie8에서 class 예약어 처리로 인해 변경

    dojo.connect(this.InfoTable, 'close', lang.hitch(this, function() {
        //this.InfoTable.destroy();
        //console.log('infoGrid (infotable.destroy)=',this.InfoGrid);
        if (this.InfoGrid) {
            //this.InfoGrid.destroyRecursive(true);
            this.InfoGrid.destroy();
            this.InfoGrid = null;
            this.InfoGrid = undefined;
        }

        this.InfoTable = null;
        this.InfoTable = undefined;
    }));

    //Border생성
    var border = new BorderContainer({
        gutters: false,
        design: 'headline',
        style: "height:100%;width:100%;"
    })

    //검색옵션 생성
    var cpT = ContentPane({
        region: "top",
        title: "검색 옵션",
        style: "height:auto;width:100%;"
    });

    this.cboService = new ComboBox({
        title: '서비스 : ',
        searchAttr: "SVC_NM",
        style: "width:120px;"
    });

    this.cboLayer = new ComboBox({
        searchAttr: "LYR_NM",
        style: "width:120px;"
    });

    var btnResult = new Button({
        iconClass : "EditButtonWidgetImage",
        style: "width:40px;margin-left:4px;"
    });
    dojo.place('<label class="widget_field_label" style=width:70px; >편집대상 :&nbsp;</label>', cpT.domNode);
    cpT.addChild(this.cboService);
    dojo.place('<label class="widget_field_label" style=width:80px;>참조레이어 :&nbsp;</label>', cpT.domNode);
    cpT.addChild(this.cboLayer);
    cpT.addChild(btnResult);

    border.addChild(cpT);

    border.placeAt(this.InfoTable.containerNode);
    border.startup();

    this.InfoTable.startup();
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If your using "dijit/form/Button" just include following class and you will see the result.

Here i have overridden the button class. Make sure to limit the scope to specific button only.

```
.claro .dijitButton .dijitButtonNode {
    background-color: transparent;
    border: none;
    box-shadow: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had faced with something similar, the solution that worked for me was to remove the `dijitButtonNode` class. But then, that would leave you with a image and no indication that it's a button. Is that what you really want?

```
domClass.remove(btnResult.domNode.childNodes[0], "dijitButtonNode")
```

Alternatively, you could simple add and `img` tag, and add a click event to it.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need to overwrite class `.dijitButtonNode` from dojo theme (in this case claro).

You can use the following CSS as starting point:

https://jsfiddle.net/zzot4zur/

```
.claro .dijitButton .dijitButtonNode {
  background-color: transparent;
  border: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  background-image: url("http://www.nuflowwidebay.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/expences-button-png-hi.png");
  background-size: 75px 30px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 75px;
  height: 30px;
}
```

---

```
require(["dijit/form/Button", "dojo/dom", "dojo/domReady!"], function(Button, dom) {
  // Create a button programmatically:
  var myButton = new Button({
    label: "Click me!",
    onClick: function() {
      // Do something:
      dom.byId("result1").innerHTML += "Thank you! ";
    }
  }, "progButtonNode").startup();
});
```

---

```
<button id="progButtonNode" type="button"></button>
<div id="result1"></div>
```